# Safari & bootstrap soft hyphenation bug: What’s going on?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, safari

In [this demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjornte/xrsh8xdw/), Safari exhibits a weird [soft hyphenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) bug when linking to [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). When `&shy;` or `&#173;` is preceded by the characters `fi`, a strange-looking character «Ṏ» ([U+1E4E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1e4e/index.htm)) shows up. I have even seen it with double umlauts:

[image: Latin Capital Letter O With Tilde And Double Diaeresis]

Any ideas what’s going on? Safari [supposedly](http://caniuse.com/#search=shy) supports `&shy;`.

Comment: "_Weird soft hyphenation bug of the day_" - is this serious meant?

Comment: @davidkonrad The question is seriously meant, yes. The bug should be reproducible if you use Safari on iOS or Mac OS X. I hope it’s OK with an informal headline over at jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After boiling down your testcase, looks like the bug is only triggered (in Bootstrap's case) when something is styled as:

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
font-weight: 500;
```

(And of course the text needs to use soft hyphens and "fi" as you described.)

You appear to have encountered [WebKit Bug 150006 - REGRESSION(r182192): Ligatures do not interact correctly with SHY in some fonts](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=150006), which was fixed in [WebKit r190891](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/190891).

Thus, your bug fortunately doesn't reproduce in current Nightly builds of WebKit (e.g. r198607). Unfortunately, Apple hasn't yet shipped a version of Safari which includes the fix. Hopefully the fix will make it into whatever release follows OS X Safari 9.1 (presumably Safari 9.2 or 10).

"ﬁ" is processed by the font engine as a (potential) [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature#Stylistic_ligatures), normally rendered so that the cross-bar of the "f" and the dot in the "i" combine into one line segment. This is why the other letter combinations in your testcase didn't trigger the bug; only "fi" had the potential to be a ligature, and thus hit the bug in the font engine when it was adjacent to a soft hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this WebKit bug is still present in Safari in iOS 9.2.3. I have encountered it using some webfonts on my webpages (for example Roboto Slab). My solution is to break a ligature by inserting Zero Width Non-Joiner special character between "f" and "i", for example:

```
f&#8204;ilter
```